# How much "Have you solved it" is appropriate in the comments?

Tags: discussion

Here I've asked a question with no solution so far:

[Why is the talkback text for a TextView read twice and the hint read as well even if the TextView is filled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396307/why-is-the-talkback-text-for-a-textview-read-twice-and-the-hint-read-as-well-eve)

Some people keep asking if I have found a solution to the problem, which I did not.
So the comments start to look like this:

"Found a solution?"

"No"

"Found a solution?"

"No"

(...)

I do not mind getting asked and pinged at all and I understand that in certain intervals it makes sense to ask the OP again if he found a solution.

But the comments start to show the pattern I've mentioned from above which offer no further information to other readers.

It also seems that people ask in the comments and do not upvote the question. Upvoting brings more attention to a question while comments won't - especially when the "Show more comments"-button hides the other comments.

I don't think that I should flag them, since asking for an update makes sense. But when is the pattern of "Found a solution?" ... "No" too much?

Comment: Yup, that's what happens when you don't answer your question.  Obligatory [xkcd link](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: Found a solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It *does* make sense to flag those comments, since they add nothing but noise. They don't clarify the question, they don't add additional information, they're not even entertaining. They're just useless noise. Especially if there are already several such comments, presumably if you'd have found a solution, you'd have posted it by now.

Comment: The only thing where I am a bit torn is "if you'd have found a solution, you'd have posted it by now" - would I? I might have completely forgotten about my question while I indeed have found a solution.

Comment: @hamena314 indeed, I let that depend on how new the OP is to the site. If I get the idea that they are not aware self-answering is a thing, I may choose to ask in a comment if the problem was solved and invite them to post it as an answer. Once. If the OP has been around the block for a while, I assume they're not answering with good reason.

Comment: @hamena As I said, it's mostly if there's already comments asking whether you've found a solution. One comment might serve a purpose, more than that surely don't.

Comment: If you allow at least one "Have solution"-comment, you run into the timing-problem: When is the last "Have solution" obsolete and another should be posted? After 1 week, month, year,...? Then the newer "Have solution" would have to stay and the oldest one flagged away. So it should be either "no Have solution" at all or chaos. Therefore I would vote for your answer -> flag all.